# Quartz Cron Expression for alternate days in a range

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

What should be my Quartz cron expression to schedule a jod to fullfill following condition ==>

i want to schedule a job which triggers every alternate day from 15 (i.e. date) of AUG to 5 of  SEP at 8:00 pm.

Like 15/2 will solve the alternate day condition but how to limit the range for two months.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the trick. The format is:

second minute hour day-of-month month day-of-week optional-year

> 0 0 20 15/2 AUG,SEP ?

Please refer to http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06 for details and examples.